# Long time to access network when windows 7 resumes from sleep

Tags: windows-7, networking

Although my machine resumes from sleep very quickly, the network access takes quite a few seconds.  Why should this be?

I have specified fixed IPs, hardcoded the DNS and gateway settings.

Any clues as to how i can speed this up?

Comment: Wireless or Wired?

Comment: I have found that the network switch was causing issues with restriction certain types of traffic.  Once i had disabled these it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the network switch was causing issues with restriction certain types of traffic. Once i had disabled these it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

how is your networkhardware defined? does it stay online during sleep or is it set to power off? The first possibility would enable wake on network  the second takes longer to come up from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this also happens when you plug in the network cable. The NIC may have problems initiating the physical connection with the switch/router/whatever you have on the other end.

Comment: i'll give that a go.

Comment: It would appear to be the Linksys switch.  When i plug the network came directly into the firewall / router box instead we get pretty much instantaneous network access.

Answer (score 0):

I have a netbook that takes closer to 30-60 seconds for the wireless to reconnect when waking from sleep mode.  I'd say a few seconds is negligible.

The only thing I would suggest is to see if the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is selected in the Adapter Properties window.

I believe that is only an option for wireless adapters.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, if you are in a domain and your server is handling dns make sure that your dns points to the server, if it points to an outside dns address it make take a while for it to log in.